Read a string from a file in assembly
I want to read a string from a file. This is what I tried but nothing is printed
Is there a problem in the way i declared the string word or in the way I am doing the reading?
.data
fisier db "input.txt", 0
mode db "r", 0
format db "%s", 0
word dd 100 dup (?)
    
.code
start:
    
    push offset mode
    push offset fisier
    call fopen
    add ESP, 8
    mov ebx, eax  
    
read:
    push ebx
    push offset format
    push offset word
    call fscanf
    add esp, 12
    
    push offset word
    push offset format
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    cmp eax, 0
    je end_reading
    
    jmp read
    
end_reading:
    push ebx 
    call fclose
    add ESP, 4
    
    
    ;apel functie exit
    push 0
    call exit
end start


You got the file pointer and the buffer address swapped in the call for fscanf. Also your cmp eax, 0 is checking the return value from printf.
